# Swift: Cast from 'Ride' to unrelated type 'NSDictionary' always fails

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building my first iOS app using Swift 2.0 and I'm running in to the following error:

> Cast from 'Ride' to unrelated type 'NSDictionary' always fails

at this line:

```
if let rowData: NSDictionary = ride as? NSDictionary,
```

Just below my class declaration I'm declaring rides like this:

```
var rides = [Ride]()
```

And above the error line I have added this:

```
let ride = self.rides[indexPath.row]
```

Screenshot:

[image]

And my Ride class:

[image]

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Why are you trying to cast between two unrelated types? Why do you think this would work?

Comment: Post your code, not a screenshot of your code.

Answer (score 1):

just cast to the proper type : Ride

```
if let rowData = ride as? Ride,
```

but as the datasource is defined as Ride anyway this check is not needed at all

**Edit:**

The properties of Ride are all declared as non optional types, so you never have to check for nil. That's a huge benefit of the Swift language

Answer (score 1):

**`struct Ride` is not a subtype of `NSDictionary`**. They are completely different concept.

Therefore, the casting `if let rowData: NSDictionary = ride as? NSDictionary` always fails.

Since `rides`'s type is `[Ride]`, `let ride = rides[indexPath.row]`'s type is `Ride`.

No optional unwrapping is required. Use the properties(name, state, ...) directly.

So, I think the code should be something like this.

```
let ride = rides[indexPath.row]
dataFull = ride.name
dataState = ride.state
dataUrlString = ride.image
...
```